# Как искать url по неточному вхождению?

Tags: python, list, поиск, условия

Пытаюсь учить питон.

**Задача**: Дан список доменов вида site.ru, site2.com и тд.

Нужно определить есть ли на этих сайтах ссылки типа site.ru/forum/1, site.ru/forum/2 и тд, т.е чтобы поиск происходил по неточному соответствию, а по определенной части урла site.ru/forum.

Заранее спасибо.

```
for link in domains:
    site_link = 'http://' + link
    session = HTMLSession()
    resp = session.get(site_link)

    all_urls = resp.html.absolute_links
    list_urls = list(all_urls) #делаю из множества лист

    if site_link + '/forum' in list_urls: #в этой строке не понимаю как правильно сделать
        print(site_link + ': forum')
    else:
        print(site_link + ': not forum')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте обойти список и проверить каждый элемент на наличие подстроки:

```
for url in list_urls:
    if site_link + '/forum' in url:
        print(url + ': forum')
    else:
        print(url + ': not forum')
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло